# Bibentry does not show cite

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

I'm trying to get a full citation inside my text using the `\bibentry` command.
But it doesn't show anything.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft=false
              ,paper=a4
              ,twoside=false
              ,fontsize=11pt
              ,headsepline
              ,BCOR10mm
              ,DIV11
              ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
   \ifXeTeX
     \usepackage{xltxtra}
   \else 
     \usepackage{luatextra}
   \fi
   \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[german,refpage]{nomencl}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rice1999optical,
  title={Optical Character Recognition: An Illustrated Guide to the Frontier},
  author={Rice, S.V. and Nagy, G. and Nartker, T.A.},
  isbn={9780792384922},
  lccn={99020879},
  series={The Springer International Series in Engineering and Computer Science},
  url={http://books.google.de/books?id=u5ofWoiONPAC},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Springer US}}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
Here i need a full Cite:
\\
\bibentry{rice1999optical}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm not sure if the problem is the same if the document has not the same scope but here's an MWE. Go crystal balls go.

Hope the MWE clarifies it! Thanks again!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Instead of show us your full preamble, just create a MWE only with the package needed for run it.

Comment: The only obvious problem so far is that you haven't given us a complete file to test.  But I also wonder about: where `\bibsstring` comes from?  where `x1`, `x2`, `x3` come from?  what does the `@article` entry have to do with the other snippets?  Not all of use have functioning crystal balls.

Comment: Got a working MWE in the edited question with the same result. The citation is not being displayed.

Comment: You want to cite? Try `\cite{rice1999optical}`

Comment: Btw: Seems you are just starting with bibliographies: Better use the modern combo of `biblatex` and `biber` from the beginning.

Comment: Ah, now perhaps the problem: Quoting from the `bibentry` manual: `The `bibentry` package will work with natbib with its native `\bibitem` format, and with standard LaTeX. Nothing else can be guaranteed.`  That said, I can get bibentry output (with errors).  I can post that as an 'answer' if you like.

Comment: If i try the `\bibitem` command, it gives me this error:
`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not campatible with author-year-citations.`

Comment: No: the manual is *not* saying use `bibitem`.  It is saying that you need to use the standard `natbib` styles.  You are using `dinnat`, which raises an error.  I'll post a (not-quite-)answer.

Answer (score 2):

The bibliography style `dinat.bst` is not fully compatible with `bibentry`.  If you push through the error it raises ---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \dinatlabel 
                       {Rice u.\,a. 1999} \textsc {Rice}, S.V.~; \textsc {Na...
l.51 \bibentry{rice1999optical}
```

You get some kind of output from `bibentry`.  I leave it to you to decide if you are happy with the output you get....

```
\documentclass[draft=false
              ,paper=a4
              ,twoside=false
              ,fontsize=11pt
              ,headsepline
              ,BCOR10mm
              ,DIV11
              ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
   \ifXeTeX
     \usepackage{xltxtra}
   \else
     \usepackage{luatextra}
   \fi
   \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rice1999optical,
  title={Optical Character Recognition: An Illustrated Guide to the Frontier},
  author={Rice, S.V. and Nagy, G. and Nartker, T.A.},
  isbn={9780792384922},
  lccn={99020879},
  series={The Springer International Series in Engineering and Computer Science},
  url={http://books.google.de/books?id=u5ofWoiONPAC},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Springer US}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage[german,refpage]{nomencl}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\nobibliography*
Here i need a full Cite:
\bibentry{rice1999optical}

% \bibliographystyle{plain}% <-- this would work (but to test, delete all auxiliary styles and complete the complete latex-bibtex-latex-latex cycle)
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. I´ll give it a try with the plain style. Are there any other suggestions to solve this?

Comment: I´ve just tested your suggestion and there's still no output generated :/

Comment: How are you compiling?  You need to run: latex, bibtex, latex, latex.  The second and third runs of latex will raise an error and you'll need to tell latex to continue the compile process regardless.  If you can explain what you are doing and how you are doing it more clearly, I (or someone else) might be able to give further hints/suggestions.

Comment: well, since i've put all the the code in there, i've run all tex compilers several times :/ Still the same result

Comment: I appreciate that you're not getting any output, but you are not being helpful regarding *what* you have tried.  '[The same result](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html)' doesn't actually provide any useful information. Did you run the commands from a terminal? from an editor? which command didn't work? the first one? the second? the third?  did you erase all auxiliary files before re-testing? ...

Comment: Ok, i thought my post clarified what i did. I've run the commands with texPad, Bibtex and latex several times. Aren't the .aux files overwritten on each compilation?

Comment: I don't know TeXPad, unfortunately.  I'd suggest trying from the command line, and pushing through the error message and see if it works that way.  Note that I'm referring that you try this with the `.tex` file I've provided, not your "real" document, which I haven't seen.  If mine works, then we can sort out why it doesn't work on your files....

Comment: The problem of bibentry not working is not exclusive to some obscure styles. See my question and example using the plain style https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679860/full-in-text-citation-without-biblatex.