# Full in text citation without biblatex

Tags: citing, bibentry

I need a full citation as would usually appear in the bibliography but in a footnote instead (I'm fine creating the footnote myself.). I have tried the bibentry package but could not get it to work. (First I ran into an incompatibility,https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424736/132815, after resolving this it still outputs nothing see also [\bibentry no output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/bibentry-no-output) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195327/132815. I already tried everything proposed there including changing the style to `plain` and including `\nobibliography{bib}` or `\bibliographi{bib}` but still nothing is output.)

Is there no working method that does not require me to change my build sequence (as biblatex apparently does).

---

My attempt at working with bibentry. Note it produces no output:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\beqselinestretch{1.2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,bm,setspace,xspace,soul,empheq}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}  % careful breaks \Tr when breaking lines.
\usepackage{colonequals} 
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{comment}     
\usepackage{siunitx}       
\usepackage{tablefootnote}


\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{geometry}         
   
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{bibentry}

% WITHOUT THE FOLLOWING LINE WE GET A LONELY ITEM ERROR:
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=darkblue, citecolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue, linktocpage%,backref=page
]{hyperref} 
% WITHOUT THE FOLLOWING LINE WE GET A LONELY ITEM ERROR:
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,enumerate,bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for ditto symbol
\newcommand*{\dittostraight}{---\textquotedbl---}



\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}


\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
    @book{goossens93,
        author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
        title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
        year = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{rmargin=1.52cm,margin=1.52cm}
    
bla

\bibentry{goossens93}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{mytestbib}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I am also facing the exact same problem, no errors and no output where expected either.